# How to use mutiple models for one dbset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

NET MVC expetrts!
I'm new in asp.NET MVC 4, so I got a simple problem not to know how to solve!

so this is my NotActivatedUsers model :

```
public class NotActivatedUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string activeCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my SignUp model :

```
public class SignUpModel
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email!")]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

and this in my dbset:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NotActivatedUser> notActivatedUser { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is " How to use my SignUp model to insert into NotActivatedUsers Dbset?

I tried this :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SignUp(SignUpModel signUpModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.notActivatedUser.Add(signUpModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(signUpModel);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I want to do "REGISTER" , but not from "NotActivatedUsers" model . because of error messages of "email" in models are different

Comment: Suppose the id and email are map to the id and email in NotActivatedUsers model, you can just create a new NotActivatedUsers entity and insert to dbset.